# How to escape single quote using awk in a bash script

Tags: bash, awk

This is what I have so far, tried multiple ways but can't get it just right.
My goal is to sanitize the input to prevent problems while inputting to mysql from text file

```
cat 'file.txt' | awk '{gsub(/'"'"'/, '.') ; print $0}' > 'file_sanitized.txt'
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332917/awk-to-replace-single-quote

Comment: As a side note, you should generally prefer `awk <script> <file>` to `cat <file> | awk <script>`.

Comment: This is not by any means guaranteed to be adequate input sanitization. Consider using bind variables instead. (Yes, this means you'll need to use a language with real database bindings for the inserts you're intending to perform. **Do that.**)

Comment: Aaron, just for knowledge what would be the reasoning for using one way over the other. I've seen both and used both.

Comment: @user152645, `cat filename | awk "$script"` has awk reading from a pipeline (a FIFO) attached to a separate `/usr/bin/cat` command; `awk "$script" filename` has awk reading directly from the file. Obviously, the latter has less overhead.

Comment: @user152645, ...also, reading straight from a file means you can seek around in the file (skipping directly to different parts by offset), you can query the file descriptor for metadata (to find out how long the file is, for instance, if you want to provide status logging about completion), and you otherwise have a more useful and functional interface than a FIFO.

Comment: @user152645, ...incidentally, `awk <filename` also has none of the overhead of `cat` and similarly provides a real FD (if the copy of awk introspects its FD 0, it can see that that's a seekable file).

Comment: @userCharlesDuffy, ...makes sense, that will be my way going forward. That's for the good feedback

Comment: BTW, take a look at the history of `mysql_escape_string` and then `mysql_real_escape_string` in PHP, and the security exploits enabled in both, to appreciate how bad of an idea this is. One can't safely escape contents without knowing the character set in use by the database server -- and even then, only using real database bindings with wire-protocol-level separation between data and code is a truly sure thing.

Comment: @user152645 I have overlooked  the part that you want to sanitize the input for a subsequent SQL import. I wouldn't have answered with `tr` / `sed` in that case. Indeed, use a programming language that comes with a library for that  kind of database and offers functions for escaping input, or even better, [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)

Comment: (Incidentally, MySQL historically didn't *have* code/data separation at the wire protocol level; this is one of the many reasons I've long considered it a toy rather than a serious tool ready for production use by people who value their data... though it's certainly much closer to being a serious database today than it was 15 years ago).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You are right and I was also surprised to hear about client-side-prepares that time (which means to escape on library level). But as you said, nowadays that shouldn't be a problem any more.

Comment: Yup. I'm just slow to let go of old grudges. (I mean, who the eff argues that **transactions** are more trouble than they're worth, and not needed unless you're building a bank? MySQL's original development team, that's who. Same thing with views and tons of other features, until they had them implemented -- at which point they were willing to admit that they might be useful and important). And then there's all the lost data from truncate-and-rewrite operations without a WAL backing the changes... but yeah, that's all days past. OTOH, databases and filesystems don't get many chances at trust.

Comment: Hehe. Yeah transactions and other features you named were a huge miss. However when I see what people are doing nowadays with NoSQL databases I wish the MySQL times back, even the early ones. ;) (I admit that there are probably 3% of valid use cases of NoSQL. The remaining would have better served by MySQL 3.0)

Comment: This is being input by myself for testing purposes, and I would never use this method for sanitizing user input. Currently using php for certain user input on intranet testing. What are your thought on " $var = preg_replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9.]/", "" , $var.   End product will be sanitized using coding language. This data is needed for quick upload for testing purposes.

Comment: @hek2mgl, ...Heh. Not all non-SQL databases are awful -- I'm quite happy about the return of Datalog (and the rise of modern implementations like Datomic, DataScript, &c). But sometimes it does seem like the wrong solution wins -- f/e, CouchDB put a ton of up-front design and documentation work into concurrency semantics... and of *course* they lose out in the market to Mongo. But then, we're getting quite far afield.

Comment: Both concepts have their use cases, sure. At the end it depends on the application programmer. In SQL times there were guys using the cartesian product, now there are people which misunderstood the schema-lessness and always need to access their data like `if 'name' in person and person.name ... else if 'surname' and person.surname ...`. The point I'm concerned about is that those people using the cartesian product were the first who fan-boyed NoSQL - because they claimed SQL is too slow for their business. ;) (Unfornatunately a high percentage were CIO, CTO etc)... But yes, that's off-topic.

Comment: wrt passing the input file to awk with `awk 'script' <filename`, just bear in mind if you do that then you lose the often-useful `FILENAME` variable and you can't do it in the very common case of parsing multiple files and you can't do "inplace editing" so the times when you would want to do that are pretty limited and so I personally just always use `awk 'script' filename` since that works in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got the problem correctly. If you want to replace all occurrences of a single quote by a dot, use `tr`:

```
tr "'" "." < file.txt > sanitized.txt
```

If you want to escape the single quote with a backslash use `sed` like this:

```
sed "s/'/\\\'/g" file.txt > sanitized.txt
```

**Note:** Please take the [advice from CharlesDuffy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468539/how-to-escape-single-quote-using-awk-in-a-bash-script/41468616#comment70143007_41468539) seriously. This is far from a stable and safe solution to escape values for an SQL import.

Comment: Worked perfect!! Thanks!!

Comment: Just use `'\''` instead of `'` in sed commands: `sed 's/'\''/\\'\''/'`. You never should enclose a command in double quotes or you run into problems when you later try to follow that same practice with a script that contains a `$`, for example.

Comment: @EdMorton Sure. But if my commands doesn't contain a lot of `$` (unlikely in sed), it looks imo better when I escape the dollar `"\$"` instead of doing the the `'\''` thing (which I hate because it is super ugly to type and look at)

Comment: Not sure why you'd think `$` is an unlikely character, but you'd also have to escape `"` and add an extra escape before `\\ `. Maybe others? It's much easier to just have 1 character to worry about than a list of them.

Comment: Unless you want to match the literal `$`, `$` is only used for the *end of input* in GNU `sed`. In `awk`, where the `$` is used to reference fields it's imo a different thing, and I find myself using `'\''`. In this example it's imo simpler to use double quotes, at least for interactive use.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is:

```
awk '{gsub(/\047/,".")}1' file
```

See http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote.

Comment: If the OP wants to replace one character by another, `tr` is what he/she wants.

Comment: The question asked was `How to escape single quote using awk in a bash script`, not `How to replace one character with another in a shell script`. Yes the minimal example posted is using that functionality in the context of changing `'` to `'.'` but it's a broader question than that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you requested "how to escape single quote using awk" here's a solution using awk:

```
awk '{ gsub("\x27", ".");print $0}'
```

where `\x27` is the escape sequence representation of the hexadecimal value 27 (a single quote).

For a list of all escape sequences see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html

Comment: No, do NOT use the hex value `\x27`, use octal `\047` instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41474373/1745001.

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong quoting:

```
awk '{gsub(/'"'"'/, "."); print}'
```

Comment: You cant do that when your script is in a file to be invoked with `awk -f script` so if you start with a one liner called from the command line and end up wanting to save it in a file you have to remember to change anywhere you did that. Personally, I just use `\047`.